# Google Contacts API can't call max-results with JQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-contacts-api

This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full',
dataType: 'jsonp',
data: { access_token: token, max-results: '5000', alt: 'json' },
success:function(data){ /*magic*/ }
});
```

The issue is that max-results has the "-" character.

How can I work around this and keep the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a string literal as the name of the property

```
$.ajax({
url: 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full',
dataType: 'jsonp',
data: { access_token: token, 'max-results': '5000', alt: 'json' },
success:function(data){ /*magic*/ }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also just made the whole request into one giant string and called it from data without an array... e.g. var dataElem = 'access_token='+token+'&max-result=5000&alt=json'; ... data: dataElem

Answer (score 0):

try this, it works for me

```
$.ajax({ url: 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=1000',
                          dataType: 'jsonp',
                          data: authParams,
                          success: function(data) {
                              console.log(data);}})
```

Comment: Here authparams var                       var authParams = gapi.auth.getToken();
                            authParams.alt = 'json';